# Missing or Invalid Field in Promoted Objects: For optimization goal APP_INSTALLS, application_id needs to be valid

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine

**Missing or Invalid Field in Promoted Objects: For optimization goal APP_INSTALLS, application_id needs to be valid. Please set it in the Promoted Objects. (#1815437)**

I get this error when trying to publish my game's ads on Facebook. I definitely integrated the SDK. I read somewhere that changing the app type to Consumer solves it, but I don't know if that is true or if it would create any complications since I'm runnig very low on time. Mine is an android game made in Unity and I need to track how many ad viewers downloaded the game.

Comment: Same error, have you found a solution on it? Thanks

Comment: Anyone found an answer to this? Trying to set up a mobile app install campaign and I'm running into this issue

Comment: Same error, have you found a solution on it?